# How can I pass maps to an Invocable Method?

Tags: apex, map, invocable-method, invocablevariable

I have a method in my code that I want to make into an invocable method:

```
// This should be an invocable method with @InvocableMethod
private void updateContacts(Map<Id,Contact> newContactMap, Map<Id,Contact> oldContactMap){
    
    for (Contact newContact : newContactMap.values())
    {
        // At this point, I absolutely need the new and old map for another class.
        if(newContact.Name == 'Example Logic'){
            OtherClass.ProcessStuff(newContactMap, oldContactMap);
        }
       
    }

}
```

And I call this method in a trigger handler like so:

```
public void onAfterUpdate(Map<Id,Contact> newContactMap, Map<Id,Contact> oldContactMap) {   
        updateContacts(newContactMap, oldContactMap);
}
```

How can I pass in the maps to the invocable method without changing the `updateContacts` method? (Changing the method parameters are fine, but ultimately it needs to work on maps later on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

- define a wrapper class with two contact list. This is needed to overcome the invocable method limit about only one parameter.
- define a new invocable method that receives a list of wrapper class instead of relying on the existing one
- create the two required maps leveraging the appropriate [constructor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_ctor)
- call the existing  `updateContacts` method

**Wrapper**:

```java
public class ContactListDTO {
   @InvocableVariable(required=true)
   public List<Contact> newContactList;

   @InvocableVariable(required=true)
   public List<Contact> oldContactList;
}
```

**Invocable method**:

```java
@InvocableMethod
public static void updateContact(List<ContactListDTO> inputContacts) {
    for (ContactListDTO dto : inputContacts) {
        Map<Id,Contact> newContactMap = new Map<Id,Contact>(dto.newContactList);
        Map<Id,Contact> oldContactMap = new Map<Id,Contact>(dto.oldContactList);
        updateContact(newContactMap, oldContactMap);
    }
}
```

Methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists because Apex supports **overloading  methods** and can distinguish between methods with different *method signatures*.

Comment: Hm, except `Only one parameter is supported on methods with @Invocable annotation`

Comment: @Josiah right! I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you Ruben.